# IPGV&M, how do I get the geocoder to prefer locations 'near me'

Tags: location, google-maps

For example, if the map is centred on Sydney and people enter 2000 in the 'move to' box it sends me to Portland rather than Sydney CBD which also has a postcode of 2000.

The [regionbound](https://regionbound.com/Drupal-IPGVM-map-configuration) description is an accurate description of my setup, except that I am not using regionbound or any special clustering rules.

The description has an 'editable box' '...replace with suburb... Australia' which seems like a clunky way to do it. I'd like a placeholder rather than text that has to be deleted if possible.